# IC current sensor functionality

Tags: current, sensor, integrated-circuit

I'm trying to understand the VOC and FAULTB pins of [this IC sensor](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/datasheets/MCR1101-xx-5_datasheet.pdf)(MCR1101-20-5).

As far as I understand, this sensor can measure -20A to +20A DC current and for the model I have the transfer function is given as:

Vout = VCC/2 + Iin x 100mV/A x VCC/5V

In my case Vcc = 5V so

Vout = 2.5V + Iin x 100mV/A

And in my application I'm going to measure a current between 0 to 5A and I want to activate an LED when the current exceeds 600mA. This could be done by a microcontroller with ADC but I wonder whether the IC already has the functinality.

It seems VOC and FAULTB pins might be used for such purpose. Can a reference Voltage be set and then the IC outputs ON or OFF when certain current passes through?

```
The overcurrent fault threshold (I ) is user-configurable via an external resistor divider and supports a range of 120% to 200% of the full-scale primary input (IP).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datasheet says : VOC range is 0 to Vcc/2.
You need use also read the fault range (depends of the model).

[image]

[image]

So, only two levels of "over range", +/- 24 A and +/- 30 A.
So, not adjustable to 600 mA. One must do externally.

Comment: I need an explicit  expansion how VOC and FAULTB works,

Comment: VOC is a voltage level "window" defined between 0 and Vcc/2 (as Vcc is also used for "reset pulse" of 5us clearing "FAULT"). if 0 < VOC < 0.225xVcc then Fault occurs at 1.2x20=+/-24 A.  if 0.225 < VOC < 0.5xVcc then Fault occurs at 1.5x20=+/-30 A.

Comment: Oh so it is not useful for my case? I want fault to occur at 600mA.

Comment: Sorry, it can't. Fault used for "absolute" protecting device ... as the max rating is IPmax is +/- 50 A for the 20A model.

Comment: I see thanks that was what I was asking about

Answer (score 0):

> *in my application I'm going to measure a current between 0 to 5A and I
> want to activate an LED when the current exceeds 600mA. This could be
> done by a microcontroller with ADC....*

Steady on now; you don't need to use a micro to do that; just a voltage comparator. After all you are considering using a voltage reference as per this: -

> *Can a reference Voltage be set and then the IC outputs ON or OFF when
> certain current passes through?*

So, just use the voltage reference on one input of a comparator and feed the analogue output signal from the sensor to the other input of the comparator.

> *but I wonder whether the IC already has the functionality*

Unfortunately the IC's fault comparator only works above the maximum limit of the linear range of the device as per the data sheet quote in your question: -

> **The overcurrent fault threshold (I ) is user-configurable via an
> external resistor divider and supports a range of 120% to 200% of the
> full-scale primary input (IP).**

Comment: In my application the treshold is 53mV. It means the I need to detect when the IC increases from 2.5V to 2.53V or more. With micro and averaging I can see that. Wouldnt that be tricky with a comparator?

Comment: Sorry 2.5 to 2.553V

Comment: You can use an op-amp that has a very low offset voltage. Op-amps are available with offset errors as low as 5 microvolts. I guess you don't need that sort of accuracy of course but, you'll have the same problem if using an ADC too and, an in-built microprocessor ADC won't be as accurate as an external op-amp or comparator. Then you also have to factor in what the sensor null output is; i.e. it won't be exactly 2.500000 volts but will have an error associated with it (probably in the millivolt range).

Comment: In other words the "zero" offset is stated in the equivalent measured current and, according to the data sheet it's typically +/- 40 mA and worst case +/-120 mA. So, when the output is exactly 2.500000 volts, the input current producing this is not 0.000000 mA but somewhere between -120 mA and +120 mA. That's got to be considered whatever solution you choose and will likely dwarf any other consideration.

Comment: You also need to consider the worst case zero-point drift with time. This is specified as -300 mA to +300 mA over 1000 hours. It's your call.